# Linux kernel development with KVM

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, virtualization

I'm trying to run Linux in a VM so I can make changes and test them quickly. I came upon this tutorial...

http://blog.vmsplice.net/2011/02/near-instant-kernel-development-cycle.html

I tried the following command (in the linux-2.6 directory, checked out via git)...
kvm -kernel arch/x86/boot/bzImage -initrd /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-10-generic -append "console=ttyS0" -nographic

I created the initrd.img-2.6.38-10-generic with the update-initramfs tool. Here is the output when I run that...

http://pastebin.com/HxGMMHSt

Failing to load some modules and not mounting anything. I think I'm missing some crucial step, I'm pretty unfamiliar with virtualization.

Running Ubuntu 11.04

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I guess you may get better response on askubuntu / superuser. You are having KVM problem, not a programming problem.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you did not installed the modules and kvm can not find them in /lib/modules. `make modules_install` may help.